# How to Display Accounts of Logged In user on clicking Accounts Tab?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, aura, lightning-tab

How to Display Accounts of Logged In user on clicking Accounts Tab using Lightning Aura Component instead of the Existing Account List? How to over ride that tab page in Lightning.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Why are you not using a List View or the existing sharing architecture? Please don't comment; [edit] your question to add information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for approach to develop this solution.

1. Build An Aura-Component (in the Init Handler, You can call to APex Method, which will check for current logged in UserId by using UserInfo Class and query all accounts owned by this User )
2. You can then display all these accounts in a lightning datatable
3. Now, go to Object Manager, Button and Links section to override the Accounts TAB as shown below:
   [image]

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Kvin.. Yes I was just looking at the approach and how to use it as a Tab. It worked.  

Comment: Sweet! @Aditya 
Happy to hear it helped you!